# Type '(s: string) => string' is not assignable to type '<T>(t: T) => T'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I declared a Typescript interface like so:

```
interface ProductFieldMapping {
  name: string,
  mapping: (p: Product) => string | number,
  formatting: <T>(t: T) => T,
}
```

And a function that returns a list of such fields like so:

```
export const mappingFunctions = (host: string): ProductFieldMapping[] => {
  const mappings = defaultFunctions(host)

  return [
    {
      name: 'title',
      mapping: mappings.productName,
      formatting: (s: string) => s,
    },
  ]
}
```

But I get this error when I want to assign to formatting this simple function `(s: string) => s`

```
Type '(s: string) => string' is not assignable to type '<T>(t: T) => 
T'.
```

What am I missing?

Possible fix:

```
type MappingResult = | string | number

interface ProductFieldMapping<T> {
  name: string,
  mapping: (p: Product) => T,
  formatting: (t: T) => T,
}

export const mappingFunctions = (host: string): ProductFieldMapping<MappingResult>[] => {
  const mappings = defaultFunctions(host)

  return [
    {
      name: 'title',
      mapping: mappings.productName,
      formatting: compose([limitSize(255), replaceNewLine(' ')]),
    }]
}
```

Comment: What's the point of generics here? Regarding the error, you can invoke `formatting<number>(...)` for example, which will be wrong obviously

Comment: Isn't the `T` in your declaration also going to be the same as what `mapping` returns? If so, seems like you need generic for the entire interface, not just the formatting method. Although given the name of the method, I'd expect it to *always* produce a string. I'm not sure how you'd "format" any other type. For example initialising `T` as a boolean doesn't make much sense as you can't produce anything but either the same value or the opposite value.

Comment: What does `formatting` do? What does it take in and what does it output? Typically a formatter would take in a value and return a string of the formatted value. Taking a type and returning the same type seems... odd.

Comment: @HereticMonkey indeed. Formatting a number will almost exclusively have to produce a string. The only times when it wouldn't is if it actually just rounds (e.g, 3.14 -> 3) or something similar (e.g, 1234 -> 1000) but that's not typically a formatting operation anyway but an actual change of the data. For most other data types returning the same type is meaningless.

Comment: @VLAZ I was going to suggest the same thing as you, moving the generic to the interface, if the OP responded as we seem to expect :).

Comment: Maybe I misleadingly called it formatting - it's just a function that transform the data in some way, for example for string it strips newlines and for numbers it could limit the number of decimals

Comment: mapping does something completely different and it doesn't require generics

Comment: @exilonX what about for booleans? Objects? `null`? If it's *only* related to what `mapping` produces, then `formatting` is not really generic independently, it's tied to `mapping`.

Comment: @VLAZ actually you are right, it is tied to what mapping produces, do you mean I should reduce the generic type T to be string | number ? It's actually not a bad idea...

Comment: I think you should introduce a generic for the entire interface, and constrain it. So `mapping` will produce `T` and `fomratting` takes `T`. That makes a lot more sense as it codifies the relationship. It also means that if `T` is `number` you cannot produce `string` from `mapping` but take `number` in `formatting`.

Comment: So what you mean is this: 

interface ProductFieldMapping<T> {
  name: string,
  mapping: (p: Product) => T,
  formatting: (t: T) => T,
}

but then I can't return an array of ProductFieldMappings{] that has also mappings that returns numbers and mappings that return strings...

Comment: How can I return that array with mapping functions and formatting functions of different types...

Comment: Given that you only have two types, it's probably easier to implement this as [a discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) (also [see here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions)). This looks basically like this `type Discriminated = A | B` and the two types have a property that allows them to be narrowed down. You'll have an array of the union but can check a property to know what `mapping` returns and `formatting` takes.

Comment: I edited the answer but I still get the same error for formatting...

Comment: @exilonX [here is an example of how a discriminated union can work](https://tsplay.dev/oN9B8m)

Comment: never knew you could do that :)) I'm a newbie to typescript it amazes me every day! Thanks @VLAZ I will try you approach see what happens! I owe you a beer :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tighten up your types by using a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) ([also see here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions)) for your possible `ProductFieldMappings`.

A discriminated union is where you have a union over multiple types but can use a property on them to narrow down the type.

```typescript
interface ProductFieldMapping<T> {
  name: keyof Product,
  mapping: (p: Product) => T,
  formatting: (t: T) => T,
}

interface StringFieldMapping extends ProductFieldMapping<string> {
    type: "string";
}

interface NumberFieldMapping extends ProductFieldMapping<number> {
    type: "number";
}

type Mapping = StringFieldMapping | NumberFieldMapping;
```

This makes the `ProductFieldMapping` a generic interface where the result of `mapping` and `formatting` are tied together and must use the same format. Since we only have two formats, we make one type for each - `StringFieldMapping` and `NumberFieldMapping`. Each of these has a distinct `type` and thus `Mapping` is now a discriminated union.

From here you can produce an array of `Mappings` and you'll know they work with the correct data:

```typescript
const numFormat = (n: number) => Math.round(n);
const strFormat = (s: string) => s.toLowerCase();

export const mappingFunctions = (host: string): Mapping[] => {
  const mappings = defaultFunctions(host);

  return [
    {                                   // OK
      name: 'title',
      type: "string",                   // it's a string
      mapping: mappings.productName,    // produces string ✔
      formatting: strFormat,            // consumes string ✔
    },
    {                                   // OK
      name: 'price',
      type: "number",                   // it's a number 
      mapping: mappings.price,          // produces number ✔
      formatting: numFormat,            // consumes number ✔
    },
    {                                   // ERROR
      name: 'a',
      type: "string",                   // it's a string
      mapping: mappings.productName,    // produces string ✔
      formatting: numFormat,            // consumes number ❌
    },
    {                                   // ERROR
      name: 'b',
      type: "number",                   // it's a number
      mapping: mappings.price,          // produces number ✔
      formatting: strFormat,            // consumes string ❌
    },
    {                                   // ERROR
      name: 'c',
      type: "string",                   // it's a string
      mapping: (p: Product) => 42,      // produces number ❌
      formatting: strFormat,            // consumes string ✔
    },
    {                                   // ERROR
      name: 'd',
      type: "number",                   // it's a number
      mapping: (p: Product) => "hello", // produces string ❌
      formatting: numFormat,            // consumes number ✔
    },
  ]
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-vjKIT5RqMMw7b9Ke8IQBtAC6bMsZAjBCjnya1qxcBxeJRcZNXkTzCD3ARYBwUAxGeuREGXe7Pd7XYA9P3kAB5ADSHbI1lsDAA5JQaBAZ5Eu69xvaxo4+1vB8gqDOmnAzewJ8gi+wGGePIwtXwhWB6bZN+Qd7eAhAmvbkIAUchP0ViloSTwzRlf8wCfbchwjER3yPLYf0GSRlzIQgt1QtCyB3McTynOwZx5JAlxPVcGDGUUoA3dDux3PcD2QMjkBPS8gKY698IgcCexfFkYPo+Cuz-OJAKVYQQLiDjex3KDbCaXiO0QjsUMopSByHABRAAldTh3U7CGVnOBCO7YjkAmX4KOUjChxo5BD3tRiIQvCFWJZe8GQ4rihRgz8+MGASAPPOiRFEy1xM4yDCWgmTlWQQAZcjkpDOwsiydw0rSdO7HDZ1EQyVzuEiyPM5KrLAfcbMCi4oHs6NHOjZzeXYiDkFfPAeOinzyD8+IAp6YKwLQySIuk2CvjihCEsUpKlJSzTtN06dkBnBAcsGYzTN6NhCuU6iStouzuyY7xfEFVpHQAFgAJlCjy3yiirYt-C0usSYDHtCqjwpNSLhu-eKFMmra1Jm9Ku0yhasGW8hVoKt7+uK0rDzIqrPkO5k70dMYNS0agMAo66Wo-X57u7TqhPK3qYcGAbPqG2Sxu4LMsiAA)

Answer (score 1):

<del>You need to give the type when you invoke the function.</del>
In your case, you should replace `string` with `T`.
<del>Because you just assign the function, not invoke it.</del>

```js
formatting: <T>(s: T) => s,
```

Then while you are invoking the function, then you give a type to your function.

```js
formatting<string>("1") // it doesn't throw error
formatting<number>(1) // it doesn't throw error
```

**EDIT**

I saw documentation has a chapter about [Generic Classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes).
There is same way which VLAZ did, but documentation used classes.

```
class GenericNumber<T> {
    zeroValue: T;
    add: (x: T, y: T) => T;
}
  
let myGenericString = new GenericNumber<string>();
myGenericString.zeroValue = "0";
myGenericString.add = function(x, y) {
    return x + y.toLocaleLowerCase(); // it works
};

let myGenericNumber = new GenericNumber<number>();
myGenericNumber.zeroValue = 0;
myGenericNumber.add = function(x, y) {
    return Math.round(y) // it works
};
```